# May I migrate this question from ELU to Linguistics?

Tags: support

May I migrate this question from ELU to Linguistics?

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/368493/112436

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear enough for what I think you want. I take it you have a space limit on this document and need a very short way to refer to "expressions that say 'I'm done, your turn", like "Transition Relevance Place" (abbreviated TRP) or "turn yielding signal". Your audience is very unlikely to know what the former means, so a technical term is unlikely to be effective. The answers you have are really good enough. Point is, naming "and yeah" won't explain the source of the problem, which is that the reporter made a recording error because of unfamiliarity with the expression. You probably need a parallel case: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_T._Evans), where the judge officially noted the reporter's error (look for the 'snitch bitch" quote).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, personally I think it's fine for Linguistics, also because I know what you're referring to in that question. You cannot migrate it yourself however, being a regular user, so flag your own question, choose the custom flag (where you can write), and describe the situation in short.

Maybe even link to this question so moderators can see that the question has been accepted (so they can migrate it).